# flutter build ipa returns: exportArchive: "Runner.app" requires a provisioning profile

Tags: ios, flutter, code-signing, codemagic

```
== Building for iOS ==

> xcode-project use-profiles
Configure code signing settings
Searching for files matching /Users/builder/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles/*.mobileprovision
Searching for files matching /Users/builder/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles/*.provisionprofile
List available code signing certificates in keychain /Users/builder/Library/codemagic-cli-tools/keychains/10-08-22_lujifhgh.keychain-db
Searching for files matching /Users/builder/clone/ios/**/*.xcodeproj
Completed configuring code signing settings
 - Using profile "codemaProfile" [cbbc5bb6-06f7-40cf-9559-50e8663dee93] for target "Runner" [Debug] from project "Runner"
 - Using profile "codemaProfile" [cbbc5bb6-06f7-40cf-9559-50e8663dee93] for target "Runner" [Profile] from project "Runner"
 - Using profile "codemaProfile" [cbbc5bb6-06f7-40cf-9559-50e8663dee93] for target "Runner" [Release] from project "Runner"
Generated options for exporting the project
 - Method: app-store
 - Provisioning Profiles:
     - com.globaltekne.dollsplasticsurgeryapp: codemaProfile
 - Signing Certificate: Apple Distribution
 - Signing Style: manual
 - Team Id: 7T9LTCB672
Saved export options to /Users/builder/export_options.plist

> flutter build ipa --release --export-options-plist /Users/builder/export_options.plist
Running "flutter pub get" in clone...                            1,916ms
Archiving com.golbaltekne.dollsplasticsurgeryapp...
Automatically signing iOS for device deployment using specified development team in Xcode project: 7T9LTCB672
Running pod install...                                           2,605ms
Running Xcode build...                                          
Xcode archive done.                                         107.6s
Built /Users/builder/clone/build/ios/archive/Runner.xcarchive.

 Building with sound null safety 

Building App Store IPA...                                        1,793ms
Encountered error while creating the IPA:
error: exportArchive: "Runner.app" requires a provisioning profile.

Try distributing the app in Xcode: "open /Users/builder/clone/build/ios/archive/Runner.xcarchive"
```

Comment: can you check if you build with the same Xcode and Flutter version as locally? and update post with version information

Comment: I'm using VSCode

Answer (score 6):

Open xcworkspace file in xcode. Select runner and select the application Target. Then select the relevant signing team. Keep the enable automatic signing option enabled. Then click on product -> archive. Once this is complete a window should appear (if not go to windows - organiser in xcode) showing the archieve. Click on distribute app then select to export or distribute. You can select release or debug mode while you distribute

[image: preview]

Comment: My "archive" menu item was disabled, because I had a simulator device selected. Once I selected "Any IOS Device" the item was enable. Took me a while to figure out my mistake.